# PlasticSCM pull existing repo into new workspace

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

I am trying to create a local workspace for a repository that I was invited to on Plastic Cloud. If I have the server name/port and repository name, how would I "clone" the project locally for me to work on. I know this is a basic question, but the Plastic docs have been super unhelpful. I was told by the person who invited me to the project that I need to search for the server in the "Cloud" section of the GUI, then when the repo shows up, right click and create a new workspace. When the repo comes up, right clicking only gives "Create New Sync View".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Join a Cloud project using the wizard

When you start Cloud Edition for the first time, you should see a screen like the following:

[image: Enter Cloud credentials]

Where you can enter your Cloud Credentials.

After you enter your credentials, you go to the next screen where you can "join an existing cloud project" and then all the local repo creation and workspace creation is done for you.

[image: Join Cloud project wizard]

### Join a Cloud project manually - screencast

In case you already had Plastic SCM installed and configured, then the wizard will not show up, but joining the project is still quite easy.

The following screencast shows how to create a local repo joined to cloud manually: https://youtu.be/ECVAHTH8Dcg.

### Join a Cloud project manually - step by step

Let's now check how to do it manually (which is the same you would do for a regular non-cloud repo you want to replicate).

First create a new local repo to host the clone from Cloud. Go to "repositories" and then click "Create new repo".

[image: Create new local repo]

Now create a new workspace for this new local repo: (you know, go to "workspaces" first...)

[image: Create new workspace for the local repo]

And finally you can pull branches from the Cloud... but you know how to do that from the sync view or even the Branch Explorer (just right click on "main" and do "pull from...").

### From the command line

By the way, it is less visual but faster from the command line:

```
cm mkrep localrep@local
cm mkwk localworkspace path_to_the_workspace
cm replicate main@cloud_repo@your_cloud_org@cloud localrep@local
```

Hope it helps!